# TCP/UDP: Send packet from one machine to another on local network

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, ip, localhost

How can I send a packet from one machine and have another machine pick it up?

The only way I can see to do this is if each machine creates an IP:port endpoint,  and I manually type the IP:port of machine A into machine B and vice versa.

Currently I have it working between two applications on my MacBook: machine A (a Processing script) sends a packet to localhost:5000

```
void UDPSendMessage( String message )
{
    String ip       = "localhost";  // the remote IP address
    int port        = 5000;         // the destination port

    udp.send( message, ip, port );

    print( "sending: " + message + "\n" );
}
```

and my C#/.NET socket receiver picks it up:

```
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any;

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint( ip, 5000 );

    Socket S = new Socket(
        ip.AddressFamily, 
        SocketType.Dgram, 
        ProtocolType.Udp
        );

    S.Bind( ep );

    S.BeginReceive(...)
```

but over a home network I won't be able to use localhost, and also I don't like the idea of hard coding a port number: what if one of the machines is already using that port?

So how can I get machine A to send out a signal and for machine B to pick it up, without any prior knowledge?

Comment: Picking a hard-coded Port number is precisely what you need to do.  That's how established applications and protocols communicate, with a known port number.  Here's a list of common ones: [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Answer (score 2):

You can discover other peers listening on the same subnet on a specific port (so you need one) by addressing the data to a [broadcast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address#IP_networking) e.g.:

```
195.255.255.255
```

Then when when you receive the data in the other machine (which you will if you bind to IPAdress.Any as you are) you can see from which address you received it from and send a reply, then when the first machine gets the reply it can see the address of who sent it!

By the way the broadcast address: 255.255.255.255, tends never to work as software, firewall and devices tend to drop such a broad broadcast.